# How to find DOM elements that exist between two other "well known" DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

How, using vanilla JavaScript can i most efficiently (and elegantly) select all elements between two other specified elements? For example, how could I pick all elements between:

`<h2>` and `<hr>` .. which would result in an `[ p, p, ul ]` ... notice the `<p>this should not be found</p>` should not be "found" since its there is no

---

after it.

I know i can write a bunch of JS to check siblings, and iterate through - but im hoping there is a more elegant way im not seeing. I'd be find if there was some querySelectorAll(..) selector machination i could use as well (or like an intersection of 2 invocations) ..

```
<div>
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>Subitle</h2>
<p>Para 1 <a href="#">link</a></p>
<p>Para 2</p>
<ul><li>A list</li></ul>
<hr/>
<h2>Another subtitle</h2>
<p>this should not be found</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to crack the Jquery nextUntil function -> http://web.archive.org/web/20210529160753/https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.nextUntil

Comment: `h2~*:not(hr,hr~*)` works if you only have on "span" of elements you need to select. If there are multiple instances of elements between an h2 and hr and you want to select them all at once then you probably need more js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a couple of possible solutions:

```js
const getChildrenInRange1 = (parent, firstChildSelector, lastChildSelector) => {
  const res = [];
  let current = parent.querySelector(firstChildSelector)?.nextElementSibling;

  while (current) {
    if (current.matches(lastChildSelector)) {
      return res;
    }

    res.push(current);
    current = current.nextElementSibling;
  }
  
  return [];
}

const getChildrenInRange2 = (parent, firstChildSelector, lastChildSelector) => {
  const afterLast = parent
    .querySelectorAll(`${firstChildSelector} ~ ${lastChildSelector} ~ *`);
  
  if (afterLast.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }
  
  const afterFirstWithoutLast = parent
    .querySelectorAll(`${firstChildSelector} ~ *:not(${lastChildSelector})`);
  
  return _.difference(afterFirstWithoutLast, afterLast);
}

const container = document.getElementById('container');

console.log(getChildrenInRange1(container, 'h2', 'hr'));
console.log(getChildrenInRange2(container, 'h2', 'hr'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Subitle</h2>
  <p>Para 1 <a href="#">link</a></p>
  <p>Para 2</p>
  <ul><li>A list</li></ul>
  <hr/>
  <h2>Another subtitle</h2>
  <p>this should not be found</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - with this, you'd have to check the that  there was a match on the lastChildSelector to return the res element, else you'd return and empty []. I think your code snippet didnt catch it because your querySelector(..) is singular and only matches on the first h2 (and not the 2nd which doesnt satisfy)

Comment: @empire29 you are correct, adding this case.

Comment: @empire29 I added another version of the solution, which is closer to what you originally implied in your question.

Comment: 2nd is cool - I’d want to replace lodash w my own diff,  but looks great! I think? I might go w the first approach as it’s a bit easier to grok - but the 2nd is quite “sexy”!